# Even after setting HOME openssh looks at wrong place for keys

Tags: ssh, cygwin, openssh

```
myhome@NOOSLLPT107144 ~
$ echo $HOME
/cygdrive/c/Users/myhome

$ ssh -vvv  git@gitlab.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
debug2: resolving "gitlab.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [52.167.219.168] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/myhome/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myhome/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myhome/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myhome/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myhome/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myhome/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myhome/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/myhome/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Comment: Why not `ssh -i /cygdrive/c/Users/myhome/.ssh/id_xxxx git@gitlab.com` ?

Comment: You are correct. `ssh` doesn't use $HOME to find the .ssh directory or the default ssh keys.

Comment: @Kenster where does it look for ? How do I configure it to different location ?